# how to return the user id when the user logged in successfully in codeigniter

Tags: codeigniter

**here is the controller to login form, after the login process the user will be able to do add posts to database, so i need to collect some data as the username of the current logged user & the id of this user in the {users table}**

```
<?php

class login extends CI_Controller{
function index()
{
    $this->load->view('login_form');
}
function proccess()
{
    $this->load->model('membership_model');
    $query = $this->membership_model->validate();

    if($query) // if the user's credentials validated ..
    {
        $data = array(
            'username_usr' => $this->input->post('username'),
            'is_logged_in' => true
        );
        $this->session->set_userdata($data);

        redirect('view=dogo&do=new_post');
    }
    else 
    {
        $this->index();
    }
}

function signup()
{
    //signup proccess
}
}
```

**and here is the model of login process**

```
<?php
class Membership_model extends CI_Model{
function validate()
{
    $this->db->where('username_usr', $this->input->post('username'));
    $this->db->where('password_usr', md5($this->input->post('password')));
    $query = $this->db->get('hs_users_usr');

    if($query->num_rows == 1)
    {
        return true;
    }
}
}
```

**I can return the username of the logged user, i need also to return the id of this user**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can return the query if it's successful and pull the user id from it:

Controller

```
<?php

class login extends CI_Controller{
function index()
{
    $this->load->view('login_form');
}
function proccess()
{
    $this->load->model('membership_model');
    $query = $this->membership_model->validate();

    if($query !== FALSE) // if the user's credentials validated ..
    {
        $user_data = $query->row();

        $data = array(
            'user_id' => $user_data->id,
            'username_usr' => $this->input->post('username'),
            'is_logged_in' => true
        );

        $this->session->set_userdata($data);

        redirect('view=dogo&do=new_post');
    }
    else 
    {
        $this->index();
    }
}

function signup()
{
    //signup proccess
}
}
```

Model

```
<?php
class Membership_model extends CI_Model{
function validate()
{
    $this->db->where('username_usr', $this->input->post('username'));
    $this->db->where('password_usr', md5($this->input->post('password')));
    $query = $this->db->get('hs_users_usr');

    if($query->num_rows == 1)
    {
        return $query;
    }
    else
    {
        return FALSE;
    }
}
}
```